# Anyone know what game uses these six-sided dice with letters and a dart-like glyph on them?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]Does anyone know what these cubes are used for? Is it a board game?

The dice are all identical, with sides, [D,S,S,T,M,Glyph].

Comment: Cubes have 6 sides, you have shown 5, what's on the 6th?  Is it a repeat of one of the other sides?

Comment: None of these, anyway... https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/word_dice_game#

Comment: @John If they're all the same, based on a few different angles visible in the big pile, I think there are two sides with an S opposite each other.

Comment: @tuskiomi LCR dice have 3 identical sides, and then each of the 3 letters on the other sides.

Comment: FWIW the "Glyph" looks to me like a [dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darts). Building from there, maybe D/T could stand for Double/Triple (rings on a dart board)...

Comment: I half expected a "dart dice" image search to find something like this, but it didn't :(

Comment: @BenjaminCosman I agree.  S = Single, D = Double, T = Triple, and the Dart = a Dart.  This probably has something to do with darts.  Not sure what the M is for.

Comment: Maybe M is for miss?

Comment: Probably just imperfections in the printing; but the glyphs don't all look the same. In the bottom picture of the individual die, it looks like an electric cord.

Answer (score 1):

While trying to track this down, I found a patent that describes something very similar to this. This die may be a further iteration of the idea described here: http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2018/0021669.html